# Does game engines (like Unreal, Unity, Crafty) add value compared to pure js frameworks (react, ember..) for my isometric tile-based games

Tags: 2d, memory-efficiency

I'd like to create a huge tile-based board (say 100K tile). The game does not have any advanced graphics (you don't see the players or landscapes), the main difficulty is that it has 100K tiles to show; [something like this](http://react.rocks/example/react-piano-tiles) (but with many more tiles) or [like this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82799/multiple-tile-drawing-in-monogame-is-slow?lq=1)

Also, I can't use any technique like in minecraft where I only show smaller "regions" at a time of the map - *all* of the map has to be shown on the screen at once (people will zoom)

Would a game engine (unity, unreal, crafty, etc) add anything *compared* to pure javascript frameworks (react, ember, etc) if the only thing you are using them for is to render a tile based board (no animated graphics or characters moving on the screen)? With each tile only showing the state of a tile (occupied or not).

I might need collision detection as 2 players can't be on the same tile (note: I don't think it would be too hard to do this in javascript)
And maybe GPU acceleration out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main importance in a case like this is to be able to use hardware acceleration and being able to upload your map to the GPU for smooth zooming.

Usually using a game engine tends to restrict how you access the hardware, whereas using OpenGL/WebGL directly will not get in your way (but also won't assist you with common tasks either).

In this case it sounds like you want to upload your map into a buffer/texture, then render it with a specialized fragment shader, alternatively [using instancing](http://www.openglsuperbible.com/2013/10/16/the-road-to-one-million-draws/) to render all those squares. With that in mind you probably won't be getting any assistance from an engine (although they may have some map implementation that you could use).

With 100k elements you can store each element as a byte in a texture/buffer and it would only take up 100kb of memory, textures commonly are 4Mb or larger for detailed meshes.

```
// Create and initialize the WebGLTexture object.
var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

var data = UInt8Array(256*256);

for(var x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
  for(var y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
    data[x*256 + 6] = (x + y) % 2;
  }
}

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, gl.GL_RGBA,
              gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

The code is untested but after the [texImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) call you have the texture loaded with your values from the for loops and can use that in your fragment shader. Updating the picture every frame [should be doable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webgl-dev-list/jhUsyB4ziPo).

Another option is to have a point list of the claimed tiles that you add more and more points to, this would reduce the amount of data to upload since you just append to the end of the buffer, but it is a little [bit more complex](http://www.geeks3d.com/20140828/test-particle-rendering-point-sprites-vs-geometry-shaders-sprites/).

Comment: Thanks, I must wait to have 15 points of reputation to upvote you (sorry). When you speak of texture, I have heard of texture atlas, is it the same thing? here is https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs255/l-49464373/m-73162938 or here https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs255/l-49464373/e-73862323/m-73162947. Is that the "texture" thing you are refering to?

Comment: @Mathieu Texture atlas is when you combine several pictures into a single texture so you can set just one texture for your objects. What I'm referring to is to make a texture/picture which contains your map information in the pixels. White being clear and black being wall for instance. Then you can make a fragment shader that calculates which pixel it should look for for this particular spot on the screen and check which color that pixel is, then draw the wall or ground depending on the result. Does that explain it better? I can expand with some pseudo code if you need

Comment: i think what you describe is what they talk about in the linked Udacity class. Thanks a lot for the reply. i'd love some pseudo code! How would you use textures to create a 100*100 grid? all tiles are "white" and the only case they get "shaded" is already occupied by a player (might be complex or too long for you, just give the basic ideas if you want, i don't wonna take too much of your time).

Comment: @Mathieu Do you mean that the only thing visible on your maps will be other players, no walls or other obstacles? I understood your question to be the opposite, no players to render and just the more or less static tiles. If the entire map can change at any point it changes how to solve the problem a fair bit

Comment: exactly only tiles (nowalls, no landscape). You don't see players (other than the fact that a tile is shaded when one player has clicked on it to claim ownership of this tile), and yes the tiles state will change all the time as players clicks them (then the tile is shaded which means unavailable to all players for the rest of the game), then he can go to click another tile,and so on...

Comment: follows my previous comment: and i might have 1000 simultaneous players each going and getting "ownership"  (by clicking ) on tiles. So not static at all:) . for the info, i think i'll use firebase to push the state of the map to 1000 clients/players at same time.

Comment: the image of the game would be just tiles, like [here (visually)](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82799/multiple-tile-drawing-in-monogame-is-slow)

Comment: @Mathieu I think you could do it with a texture still (I updated my answer with a bit of untested code), you would have to test it a bit. It might make more sense to look into point sprites though (also in the answer) since it offloads more work on the GPU.

Comment: thanks a lot i will probably use sht that goes in this direction